# Calculating sum of digits of 2^n in C

Tags: c, int

I am new to C and trying to write a program that calculates the sum of the digits of 2^n, where **n<10^8.**

For example, for 2^10, we'd have 1+0+2+4, which is 7.

Here's what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
   int n, t, sum = 0, remainder;

   printf("Enter an integer\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   t = pow(2, n);

   while (t != 0)
   {
      remainder = t % 10;
      sum       = sum + remainder;
      t         = t / 10;
   }

   printf("Sum of digits of 2 to the power of %d = %d\n", n, sum);

   return 0;
}
```

The problem is: the program works fine with numbers smaller than 30. Once I set n to a number higher than 30, the result is always **-47**.

I really do not understand this error and what causes it.

Comment: use 64-bit integers, try `long long int n, t, sum = 0, remainder;` for example; and as extra credit - try to find a solution for very large n (with 64-bit it will be still limited)

Comment: What’s the highest `n` you need to support?

Comment: @Ry- , it needs to work for any value of n.

Comment: @flowz0r: You mean any value of `n` while remaining an `int`? So up to `INT_MAX`, which could be 32,767 or 2,147,483,647?

Comment: @Ry-, exactly. It has to be bigger than 0, that's the only condition. There's no upper limit.

Comment: In practice, there’s going to be an upper limit, so it’s probably a good idea to find out what you actually need to support.

Comment: @Ry-, let's just say  n < 10^8 for this example.

Comment: Please edit the question adding that piece of information (that you want to calculate the sum of digits of 2^n where **n** is < 10^8), which is kind of important (note that a 64-bit `long long` cant store, say, 2^65). Are there any other requirements that should be disclosed?

Comment: @Bob__ , sorry about that. I originally didn't think about an upper limit (didn't even think I had to, tbh), as this was just a project for fun. I will add the remark now. No other requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interesting problem to be sure, but I think the solution is way outside the scope of a simple answer if you wish to support large values of *n*, such as the 10<sup>8</sup> you mentioned. The number 2<sup>10<sup>8</sup></sup> requires 10<sup>8</sup> + 1 (100,000,001) bits, or around 12 megabytes of memory, to store *in binary*. In decimal it has around 30 million digits.

Your `int` is 32 bits wide, which is why the signed `int` can't store 2<sup>31</sup> – the 32nd bit is the sign while 2<sup>31</sup> has a 1 followed by 31 zeros in binary, requiring 32 bits without the sign. So it overflows and is interpreted as a negative number. (Technically signed integer overflow is undefined behaviour in C.)

You can switch to an `unsigned int` to get rid of the sign and the undefined behaviour, in which case your new highest supported *n* will be 31. You almost certainly have 64-bit integers available, and perhaps even 128-bit, but 2<sup>127</sup> is still way less than 2<sup>100000000</sup>.

So either you need to find an algorithm to compute the decimal digits of a power of 2 without actually storing them (and only store the sum), or forget about trying to use any scalar types in standard C and get (or implement) an arbitrary precision math library operating on arrays (of bits, decimal digits, or binary-coded decimal digits). Alternatively, you can limit your solution to, say, `uint64_t`, but then you have *n* < 64, which is not nearly as interesting… =)

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. I found this problem in an first year computer science university exercise book, so I assumed it would be quite easy. I guess I was wrong. I will try to look into it more and maybe come up with a solution, as it's quite an interesting problem indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

For `signed int t = pow(2,n)`, if `n >= 31` then `t > INT_MAX`.

You can use `unsigned long long t = pow(2,n)` instead.

This will allow you to go as up as `n == 63`.

Also, since you're using base `2`, you can use `(unsigned long long)1 << n` instead of `pow(2,n)`.

Comment: `1ULL << n`, rather than 2.

Comment: @Ry: Yes, I figured that the `<<` would look "strange" enough for this dude, so I didn't wanna overload him with too many new things at once.

Comment: I think `63` here is a typo for `CHAR_BIT * sizeof (unsigned long long) - 1`.

Comment: @TobySpeight: You are correct, and this also hold for the `31` above it. The general answer is that all of this depends on `limits.h`, but again - **under the given context**, I figured that the simpler the answer was, the better it would serve the purpose of helping the (rather inexperienced) person who asked the question.